# regex for searching through dataframe in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of barcodes with the format: AAACCTGAGCGTCAAG-1
The letters can be A, C, G or T and the number after the dash can be 1 - 16.

```
barcode = c('AAACCTGAGCGTCAAG-1',
            'AAACCTGAGTACCGGA-1',
            'AAACCTGCAGCTGCTG-1',
            'AAACCTGCATCACGAT-3',
            'AAACCTGCATTGGGCC-5',
            'AAACCTGGTATAGTAG-10',
            'AAACCTGGTCGCGTGT-1',
            'AAACCTGGTTTCCACC-16',
            'AAACCTGTCATGCATG-14',
            'AAACCTGTCGCAGGCT-15',
            'AAACGGGAGAACTCGG-1')
cluster = c(6,3,6,16,17,11,14,18,9,8,14)
df <- data.frame(Barcode = barcode, Cluster = cluster)
```

I need to subset this dataframe based on the -# at the end of the barcode. I have been using this to subset the dataframe. The problem is this works for every number except 1.

```
> df[grep("([ACGT]-10){1}", df$Barcode),]
              Barcode Cluster
6 AAACCTGGTATAGTAG-10      11
```

When I use the following, it will include all the barcodes that end in -1, as well as -10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15 and -16.

```
> df[grep("([ACGT]-1){1}", df$Barcode),]
               Barcode Cluster
1   AAACCTGAGCGTCAAG-1       6
2   AAACCTGAGTACCGGA-1       3
3   AAACCTGCAGCTGCTG-1       6
6  AAACCTGGTATAGTAG-10      11
7   AAACCTGGTCGCGTGT-1      14
8  AAACCTGGTTTCCACC-16      18
9  AAACCTGTCATGCATG-14       9
10 AAACCTGTCGCAGGCT-15       8
11  AAACGGGAGAACTCGG-1      14
>
```

Is there a regex that will include barcodes ending in -1, but exclude all other barcodes that end in numbers from 10 - 16?
I want to subset the dataframe so that I only get this:

```
               Barcode Cluster
1   AAACCTGAGCGTCAAG-1       6
2   AAACCTGAGTACCGGA-1       3
3   AAACCTGCAGCTGCTG-1       6
7   AAACCTGGTCGCGTGT-1      14
11  AAACGGGAGAACTCGG-1      14
>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just fixed it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
df[grep("-1$", df$Barcode),]
```

This matches 1 at the end of the string, but also requires that the digit before 1 is not 1, so you don't match 11

```
              Barcode Cluster
1  AAACCTGAGCGTCAAG-1       6
2  AAACCTGAGTACCGGA-1       3
3  AAACCTGCAGCTGCTG-1       6
7  AAACCTGGTCGCGTGT-1      14
11 AAACGGGAGAACTCGG-1      14
```

Comment: Seems adequate to use `"-1$"`...? There's also an `endsWith` function for this.

Comment: @Frank Oh duh, I guess if 16 is the max and we're only matching 1s I've made it way more complicated than it needs to be

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `df[grep("([ACGT]-1$){1}", df$Barcode),]`

You can just use a $ to specify the end of the chain. See more information here on "pattern" use: http://www.jdatalab.com/data_science_and_data_mining/2017/03/20/regular-expression-R.html